# Is this version a minor or major change?

Tags: node.js, semantic-versioning

I had new changes to my code. These changes use new Node 14 features, such as Optional Chaining. This has caused problems for clients running version 12 of Node.

Should this new version be major or not?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: you almost certainly should have released that as a major version, yes.

---

As I see it, there are three possibilities, depending on the package's declared Node version support (usually included as `$.engines.node` in `package.json`):

1. You **explicitly supported Node 12**, and are now *dropping* that support.

   This requires a major version change, your changes are not backwards-compatible. Steps to mitigate, assuming the current version is `x.y.z`:

   - Re-release the new version that uses incompatible syntax as `(x+1).0.0`;
   - Release a new version `x.y.(z+1)`, reverting the changes to restore Node 12 compatibility, to get folks' builds passing again; and
   - Consider releasing `x.(y+1).0`, implementing the new functionality with backwards-compatible syntax (as Node 12 is still in LTS, see #3).
2. You **explicitly didn't support Node 12**.

   This doesn't require a major version change. Nobody should have been using it with Node 12 to begin with and it's not really your fault they're now having problems.

   That said, given that people apparently *were* using it with Node 12 (which is still in LTS, see #3), you may *choose* to support them by doing the steps in #1 anyway.
3. There was **no/unclear explicit Node version support**.

   In the absence of an explicit support declaration, I would go back to [Node's own support](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) - Node 12 is still in LTS until the end of April 2022. Therefore I'd expect any actively maintained package that *didn't* specify otherwise to continue to support Node 12 usage too. You should therefore follow the mitigation steps in #1.

   I would also consider being more explicit about what is required/supported, by adding the information mentioned above to the package file in all of the new releases (e.g. for the optional chaining in `(x+1).0.0`, per [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----), `">=14.0.0"`).

Finally I would note that you can use the latest syntax in your source code but still support older Node versions through *transpilation*, publishing code generated by e.g. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) rather than the source code itself.